# Excluding an optional argument when instantiating a class

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a class that looks like so:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({ argA, argB, argC }) {
    this.ac = new AwesomeClass({
      argA,
      argB,
      argC,
    })
  }
```

Works fine, but now sometimes I want to pass an additional argument, `argD` when creating things.  But not always.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor({ argA, argB, argC, argD }) {
    this.ac = new AwesomeClass({
      argA,
      argB,
      argC,
      argD, //<--don't include if argD is undefined
    })
  }
```

The trouble is `AwesomeClass` shouldn't be instantiated with a default `argD` parameter (such as an empty object), as that will cause issues.  Either I intentionally pass a value for `argD` to it, or no argument at all.

Is there a good way to do this other than manually checking if `argD` is `undefined` and instantiating `AwesomeClass` with or without that parameter?

Comment: Your contrived toy example makes no sense. Why not just instantiate AwesomeClass directly. Do you have a concrete use case we can direct an answer toward? Or is this just a inquiry about polymorphism in JavaScript?

Comment: @RandyCasburn there's more to `MyClass` than shown here.  I just trimmed it down to focus on the issue at hand

Comment: The issue is not with `MyClass`. The issue is that `AwesomeClass` distinguishes between an `undefined` property and no property at all, which it shouldn't. An `undefined` argument should be semantically equivalent to no argument at all - default parameter initialisers do this as well.

Comment: why don't you do this :
`constructor(args) { this.ac = new AwesomeClass(args) }`